# tikz: Add squares (nodes) to graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw some graphs in LaTex, i am trying to draw this minimal graph[image].

So far i have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,
            thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries},every path/.style= {>=latex}]      
\node[main node] (a) {A};
\node[main node] (b) [below = 2.4cm  of a] {B};
\node[main node] (c) [below right = 1.2cm and 1.5cm of a] {C};

\path
  (a) edge node {} (c)
  (b) edge [bend right] node {} (c)
  (c) edge node[above] {} (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but i cannot to draw the yellow squares. Can you someone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

You can use exactly the same strategy you've used so far, to place nodes and draw arrows between them. One possible style definition for the yellow squares is

```
yellow box/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow, minimum size=8mm}
```

[image]

In my example here the arrows are arranged differently than in your image, but that is because you had two arrows between `b` and `c` in your code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % supersedes arrows
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->, >=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, % Stealth from arrows.meta instead of stealth' from arrows
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries},
    every path/.style={>=latex},
    yellow box/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow, minimum size=8mm}
]

\node[main node] (a) {A};
\node[main node] (b) [below = 2cm  of a] {B};
\node[main node] (c) [below right = 1.2cm and 2.5cm of a] {C};

\node[yellow box, right=of a] (i1) {inf\textsubscript{1}};
\path (b) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i2) {inf\textsubscript{2}} (c);
\node[yellow box, below right=2mm and -2mm of i2] (i3) {inf\textsubscript{3}};


% note that you don't need the empty node {} after each edge
\path
  (a) edge (i1)
  (i1) edge (c)
  (b) edge[bend right]  (i3)
  (i3) edge[bend right] (c)
  (c) edge (i2)
  (i2) edge (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```